# Why do I need a Semi Colon after a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working my way through a tutorial on msdn http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1 and I came to this part where it asked me to create a list and after the list was closed it had a semi colon outside of the parenthesis like so

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var genres = new List<Genre>
    {
        new Genre { Name = "Disco"},
        new Genre { Name = "Jazz"},
        new Genre { Name = "Rock"}
    };
    return View(genres);
 }
```

I'm new to c# and wanted to find out why I had to do this as I'm creating notes to build a knowledge base for myself. I've seen it used before in other languages I'm sure but I never questioned it but it's bugged me for a while

Comment: A semicolon ends a statement in C# ( and other languages).

Comment: If your new to c# then it sounds like this tutorial is a little bit advanced for you as alot of the syntax is "shortcutty". basically just treat it as the end of the code line

Comment: `;` terminates the statement. That's how it is deigned. So you've to..

Comment: @TimSchmelter I knew that I'm not new to programming just never understood why its outside of the parenthesis

Comment: it's not merely with Lists that you end them with a ';', but all statements as @TimSchmelter said, must end with the same. It is hardwired syntax and you can't skip it. :)

Comment: @Sayse I'm new to c# in this sense I must add I've made windows forms applications but now im looking into asp.net mvc 4 applications. The turtorials have been a great help

Comment: @Crouch, because it marks the end of the statement creating the list.

Comment: @Crouch - My intention was to point out that the line of code you are questioning is basically merging together multiple lines of code into 1... i.e `genres = new List<G>();var g= new Genre(); g.Name = "Disco";..` etc

Comment: Yeah that was my assumption as to what the semi colon was doing but I was merely trying to understand why it was outside of the parenthesis. Cheers for the contribution @Sayse

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think the asker may be confused because some statements that have a _block_ `{ ... }` do not end with a semicolon after the block. For example with the code `if (condition) { DoA(); DoB(); }`, the `if` statement is a statement that does not end with a semicolon. However, the braces `{ ... }` present in a collection initializer are ___not___ similar to the braces `{ ... }` that create a block in an `if` (or `foreach`, `while` etc.) statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking at a list initializer.

Instead of doing

```
var genres = new List<Genre>();
genres.add(new Genre { Name = "Disco" });
genres.add(new Genre { Name = "Jazz" });
genres.add(new Genre { Name = "Rock" });
```

You can initialize the list with exact Genres already in it. Very much the same way you also added `Name` to your `Genre` objects.

The semicolon after the list initialization is a simple statement ending. The colons after the different genres are used to separate entries in your initializer.

Comment: This was exactly the answer I was after not the comments I've had further up where people assume I don't understand a semi colon ends a line of code. Cheers dude

Comment: @Crouch: [Collection Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx) is the term you have searched ( you cannot only initialize lists in this way ).

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not very interesting, so I come up with a larger example:

```
namespace Test
{
  delegate int MyDel(); // semicolon required after delegate type declaration

  abstract class Class
  {
    int Field1;      // semicolon required after field
    int Field2 = -1; // semicolon required after field with initializer

    int Property1
    {
      get
      {
        return 42; // semicolon required after statement
      }  // semicolon disallowed after end of accessor body
      set
      {
      }  // semicolon disallowed after end of accessor body
    } // semicolon disallowed after end of property block

    int Method1()
    {
      Some.Statement.Here(); // semicolon required after statement
      Some.Statement.Here(); // semicolon required after statement
      ;                      // extra semicolon means empty statement here, OK
      return 10;             // semicolon required after statement
    }                        // semicolon disallowed after end of method body

    protected abstract int Method2();  // semicolon required when method block or accessor block is absent
  }; // semicolon optional after declaration of class, struct, interface, enum
}; // semicolon optional after namespace block
```

As you see, for every semicolon and for every end brace `}` I have indicated whether a semicolon `;` is required, optional or disallowed.

Your example is simply an example of the rule *semicolon required after statement*. Note that a semicolon is required after the last statement (of some block) too, so it is not just in between statements.

For commas `,`, in some cases a comma is optional after the last item, as in:

```
new List<int> { 2, 4, 6, }
```

or

```
enum Color { Blue, Yellow, Red, Green, }
```

but for method argument lists and parameter lists a comma is disallowed after the last item:

```
MyCall(2, 4, 6)
```